# Run 3 parallel downloads and cancel all at any time

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, wget

I need a bash script that can do the following:

1. Download 3 files in parallel using wget, they don't have to finish at the same time.
2. Be able to cancel the 3 downloads at the same time with `CTRL+C` (except those that have finished already).

Currently I run 3 parallel instances of `wget -c URL` each one on its own terminal. But would like just to have a script that is waiting for user input to cancel, so I can continue after Linux reboot.

My systems is Windows with Cygwin.

Comment: It's doable but complex. You would rely on SIGINT trapping and running and managing processes in the background. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GNU `parallel` for that. Put the URLs in an array and then run `wget` with `parallel`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
urls=( "https://example.com" "https://example1.com" "https://example2.com")

parallel wget -c ::: "${urls[@]}"
```

Parallel will run the commands in parallel, and stopping the script (e.g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will kill parallel, killing all three running wget instances, while not affecting any that have already finished.

You should be able to find `parallel` in the repositories of your operating system.

---

If you don't want to or can't install `parallel`, you could also do this natively in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT

urls=( "https://example.com" "https://example1.com" "https://example2.com" )
for url in "${urls[@]}"; do
  wget -c "$url" &
done

wait
```

The trick here is using the `trap` builtin (see `help trap` in bash) to *trap* the command `kill $(jobs -p)` to the EXIT signal. `jobs -p` will return the PIDs of any child processes of the current shell, so in this case it will be the PIDs of the running `wget` processes. These are passed to `kill` which kills them. So when you kill the script, that gets passed on to its children. The `wait` ensures the script will wait until all background jobs have finished running before exiting so that you can still kill the script and, by extension, the `wget` processes, with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Your command does not work with `parallel` from `moreutils-0.66-1`.

Comment: Also the `for` is not parallel.

Comment: @Smeterlink it should work with `parallel`. What does "not work" mean? Do you see any errors? Please edit your question and show what you tried so I can see what might have gone wrong. I tested this with a very similar command and it worked as expected, and I also tested that exact script with those URLs (they are valid URLs) and it worked. The `for` was indeed not parallel. Sorry, I had forgotten to send the jobs to the background; fixed now.

Comment: My first thought when I saw the problem was also GNU parallel. I've not tried the one included in moreutils, but that's probably not GNU parallel.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity Ah! Yes, I now see that on my system (Arch) I have both a `parallel` and a `parallel-moreutils` executable installed. Thanks!

Comment: @Smeterlink you need to install GNU `parallel`, and _not_ the parallel from moreutils. If you tell us your operating system, I can tell you how to install it.

Comment: @terdon I'm on Windows with Cygwin. I mean that when I run the script it just closes directly, the process does not wait to be closed. `parallel` does not work for me.

Comment: @Smeterlink please edit your question and mention you're on cygwin! That is very relevant. Anyway, can you install GNU parallel on it? This is NOT the parallel from moreutils.

Comment: @terdon installed GNU parallel in Cygwin following this guide: https://gist.github.com/drhirsch/e0295105a36039aa38ce936f39b26301

However does not work, outputs error `parallel: Warning: Finding the maximal command line length. This may take up to 30 seconds.`.

Comment: @terdon ok looks like it works, but can't see any output from the commands, only all the `wget` the processes on task manager.

Comment: @Smeterlink what output? Wget doesn't have output. You should see the three files have now been downloaded, and you should also see wget's error output (progress info) in your terminal.

Comment: @terdon yes `wget` displays the output progress as it's being downloaded, however with `parallel` that's not the case. I only get the notification once download is completed.

Comment: @Smeterlink I can't reproduce that on my system, I'm afraid. But if that is something you need, please add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Bash script in [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/683946/108618) needs a trap because Bash runs commands (including asynchronous commands) in separate process groups. It's the terminal who knows the foreground process group and sends SIGINT to the group upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. When the Bash script `wait`s in the foreground, the `bash` itself is in the foreground process group, but not `wget`s it spawned. SIGINT (if any) gets to `bash`, not to `wget`s. This is why you need the trap in the mentioned answer.

Other shells may work differently. In my Kubuntu `posh` does not create new process groups, it runs everything in the process group it belongs to. This fact allows us to simplify the script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/posh

set -- 'https://example.com' 'https://example1.com' 'https://example2.com'
for url do
  wget -c "$url" &
done

wait
```

If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> when our script is running in the foreground, the terminal will straightforwardly send SIGINT to `posh` *and* to `wget`s because they will be in the same process group being the foreground process group.

Notes:

- `posh` does not support arrays, so I saved the URLs as positional parameters. You can delete the `set …` line; then specify URLs when invoking the script (e.g. `./the_script 'https://example.com' 'https://example1.com' 'https://example2.com'`). This way you turn the script into a tool for downloading arbitrary things in parallel.
- The other answer uses `kill` in the trap and the default signal is SIGTERM which is different than SIGINT (although `wget` probably reacts in the same way). You can make `kill` send SIGINT or whatever, it's your choice (`kill -s …`). In our script we cannot choose. We don't relay any signal, we don't generate any signal. We set things up in the first place, so upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> the terminal sends SIGINT not only to the shell interpreting the script, but also to `wget`s.

The other answer is good, GNU `parallel` is the right tool, Bash with `trap` should work; so in some sense my answer is unnecessary. Still I wanted to show you that knowing how <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> works and how different shells work you can get the behavior you want just by choosing a different shell.

Comment: `posh` does not work on `Cygwin`. For each link says `: not found`. Can I just do it normally?, there are just a few links.